# Image under anchor tag onmouseover highlighted background color not changing

Tags: html, css, hover, anchor, onmouseover

Here is my code onmouseover on image under anchor tag highlighted color not changing please can I know what am doing wrong

```
 <div class="iconlink">
  <a href="/Classification/ClassificationLabel" title="Classification Label">
  <img src="/Content/Images/labels-72x72.png" /><div>Classification Label</div>
     </a>
    </div>
```

i tried with these types

```
.iconlink a:hover {background-color: #000000;
    color: #000000;0}
```

and

```
<div class="iconlink">
  <a href="/Classification/ClassificationLabel" title="Classification Label" class="hove"> 
<img src="/Content/Images/labels-72x72.png" /><div>Classification Label</div>
  </a>
   </div>
 .hove:hover{background-color: #000000;
    color: #000000;}
```

Comment: Is [THAT](http://jsfiddle.net/ZutbT/) what u want?

Comment: yes exactly same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `background-color` to your `img` in css like:

```
.iconlink a:hover img {
  background-color: #000;
}

.iconlink a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZutbT/1/)